# Get accessTime of a file

Tags: android, android-file, lastaccesstime

I need a method of getting the last time a (local) file has been accessed in android.

I don't mean `file.lastModified()`, but the last time it had been opened (viewed in any app of the device).
I have bunch of files that are only viewed, not modified, and i want to delete the files that has been accessed longest time ago to free up space.

I stumbled across [this piece of code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2724009/10470378) using `java.nio.file` package:

```
File file = //file from context.getExternalFilesDir(dirName)
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file.toPath(), 
BasicFileAttributes.class);
long accessedAt = attr.lastAccessTime().toMillis();
```

- Can someone confirm that this actually works and retrieve the last time the file has been accessed?
- Is this even possible to achieve in android?
- This code requires API level 26 and above, is there any way to so with 21 <= *API level* < 26 ?

Comment: Bear in mind that Google is eliminating most filesystem access in Android Q, so your app will not work in the long term.

Comment: That's bad news. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407071/file-last-access-time-on-android

Comment: I'll check that, thanks @fancyjyl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55443419/get-accesstime-of-a-file#comment97602374_55443419) by [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware), using java.nio.file, android.system.Os or other built in libraries to achieve my goal won't work well with future android versions.

So i ended up using a local DB [(android room)](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) for handling the access to app's files (only when accessing from my own app obviously).

Each row has `long lastAccessTime` and `String filePath` columns.
For each file accessed i inserted(if it's the first time)/updated its record with `new Date().getTime()`.

When freeing up space, i queried for those records ordered by `lastAccessTime ASC`, so the oldest will be first. After a file was deleted, updated the relevant record.

This approach was possible because all of the files were stored in a dedicated directory (using [getExternalFilesDir](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String))) and were managed only by my application.